# Doorkeeper and Devise parsing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, doorkeeper

I am using doorkeeper with devise to authenticate a user. However, the user has a many-to-many relation with another table called branch and I want to relate the access token created with that branch.

When I logged in through devise, the user would be asked to input branch name, email, and password. I created a new warden strategy to authenticate the user and check whether the provided branch belongs to the user or not.

I do not know how I can actually parse the information of the branch to the doorkeeper to create the access token. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the related code, so that we can help you

Comment: I ended up pass the query parameters from the client to the doorkeeper so I can customize some doorkeeper classes to read that parameters

Comment: Here are a few posts regarding issues you might stumble upon... have a look  https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/?s=doorkeeper